# InActive Sessions not terminating in Oracle

Tags: oracle, session, service, timeout

I have a .NET Service which keeps polling Oracle Database to get records every 2 mins.

But service stops communicating with Oracle after few hours of run, and throws exception.

I verified at DB level and found there were 155 INACTIVE sessions. I restarted my service and then when I checked there were around 70 INACTIVE sessions for my service.

This process is causing an exception in my service and hence interrupting the work. Can anyone please help me in understanding where is the problem?

Why do not it closes the session or re-use the existing one.

Comment: You say it "throws exception".  It would be very helpful if you specified what exception your'e getting.  It is very difficult for us to guess.  If you're looking in `v$session`, a session is `INACTIVE` when it is not executing a SQL statement at that particular instant.  The vast majority of sessions will be inactive for the vast majority of time.

Comment: I was not closing connections properly. I identified and closed them at the place and its working smooth now. Thanks Justin Cave.

Answer (score 0):

I came to know that in my code Connections to database were not getting closed. I analysed again the whole thing, and closed the connection sin finally block. And it is working smoothly now. Thanks.